# Range of values - how to determine without if loop?

Tags: c#, .net, range

I need to find the `sun-sign` of a given person based on his age.

For eg,

```
Capricorn   December 22 – January 20
Aquarius    January 21 – February 18
Pisces      February 19 – March 19
Aries       March 20 – April 19
Taurus      April 20 – May 20
Gemini      May 21 – June 20
Cancer      June 21 – July 22
Leo         July 23 – August 22
Virgo       August 23 – September 22
Libra       September 23 – October 22
Scorpio     October 23 – November 21
Sagittarius November 22 – December 21
```

I wrote this code,

```
 public enum Months
 {
     January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December,
 }

var person = new Person(name:"mady", age:20, dateTime: new DateTime(2011,09,16));
if (person.DOB.Month == (int)Months.December) 
{
    if (person.DOB.Day >= 22)
        return "Capricorn";
    else
        return "Sagittarius";
} ...
....
....
....
```

The `IF` statements grow consistently and might become a nightmare if tomorrow the list grows.

Is there an elegant way of finding out the Sunsign ? `Enumerable` or `Range` in .NET doesn't seem to fit this case or is this the only way of writing the code ?

Comment: What do you mean by "if tomorrow the list grows"? I would create just 12 sign start dates and compare the DOB with each, to find the two dates which encapsulate the DOB.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I guess OP doesn't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: "if tomorrow the list grows" -- The list hasn't changed much in the past 100 years. ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi I heard there's a 13th sign but people have problems adjusting, so it just ignored :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a class StarSign:

```
class StarSign
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly DateTime StartDate;
    public readonly DateTime EndDate;

    public bool Contains(DateTime date);
}
```

Add all the star signs to a collection StarSigns. Then for any given DateTime date (of the person) do

```
foreach (var sign in StarSigns)
{
    if (sign.Contains(date))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a: " + sign.Name);
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit, responding to your comment:

The Contains function can easily compare dates, just make sure you ignore the year:

```
public bool Contains(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime startNoYear = new DateTime(1904, StartDate.Month, StartDate.Day);
    DateTime endNoYear = new DateTime(1904, EndDate.Month, EndDate.Day);
    DateTime dateNoYear = new DateTime(1904, date.Month, date.Day);

    return dateNoYear >= startNoYear && dateNoYear <= endNoYear;
}
```

So yes, if you have many many StarSigns, this will affect performance. Normaly you will only have 12, and since you know you are dealing with a closed set, you can afford to do it this way.

When it comes to optimization, you will also want to store startNoYear and endNoYear and not calculate them each time you run Contains. Calculate them in the constructor; I'm only doing it in the method so it's easier to understand. Even faster would be to work on DateTime properties directly and avoid creating new DateTime objects altogether. As far as this example goes, I opt for simplicity over optimization.

Comment: You can also use Linq `StarSigns.First(s => s.Contains(date))`

Comment: Yup, once you have the leg work there are lots of easy options!

Comment: @DavidBožjak: Great answer. Thanks. 1. BTW, kindly show me the definition of `Contains` method. 2. Assuming there are `1000 sun-signs`, then `1000 instances of the classes will be produced` leading to performance degradation ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I added an example of the implementation of the Contains method. There are other ways to do it, but that one should be easy to understand. Then you can improve and optimize depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks to the discussion on the Heinzi's answer, I've changed the year in the implementation to a leap year: 1904.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can compare dates:

```
if (new DateTime(2012, 1, 1) < new DateTime(2012, 2, 1)) ...
```

Thus, I would suggest that

- you normalize the DOB to a given leap year (e.g. 1904)
- and then simply use date comparisons:

  ```
  DateTime dob = new DateTime(1904, person.DOB.Month, person.DOB.Day);

  if (dob >= new DateTime(1904, 12, 21))
      return "Aquarius";
  else if (dob >= new DateTime(1904, 11, 22))
      return "Sagittarius";
  else if (dob >= new DateTime(1904, 10, 23))
      return "Scorpio";
  ...
  else
      return "Aquarius";
  ```

An obvious improvement would be to create a `List<Tuple<DateTime, String>>` and iterate through that. However, since the dates are very unlikely to change in the next hundred years, hardcoding them in the `if` conditions might suffice.

Comment: You should use a leap year for your datum, otherwise your code will blow up if the person was born on a leap day.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: There is no sign boundary on 29 Feb or 1 Mar, so why would that cause a problem?

Comment: @RoyDictus: Matthew is right, `new DateTime(1900, 2, 29)` throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Will fix.

Comment: @RoyDictus Because if `dob.Month` is 2 and `dob.Day` is 29, then this line will explode: `DateTime dob1900 = new DateTime(1900, dob.Month, dob.Day);`

Comment: @Heinzi: Ah you mean on the first line... OK... So instead of 1900 you could use 1904.

Comment: @Heinzi: Now, I understood the meaning why you normalize the DOB to a given leap year (e.g. 1904). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch statement

```
switch (person.DOB.Month)
 {
   .....
   case 12:
      if (day >= 22) return "Capricorn"; else return "Sagittarius";
      break;
   .......

 }
```

Comment: Nice abuse of the fact that a month contains two signs.
@OP: Use a Enumeration instead of String constants to reder
 to the signs

Answer (score 0):

May you could build a small Dictionary of sun-sign, which stors the Name of the sun sign as key and it's timespan as value. The timespan would be the first to the last date.
Then there a standard time function to tell if the persons DOB is in the timespan. Mayb you need to strip out the year of birth, but that should be easy.

As a final touch you could use linq:

```
var sunsigns as Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
// adding sun-signs here

var sunsign = (from s in sunsigns where (methodToTellIfItsinRange(s)) select s).first();
```

Answer (score 0):

linq is good..   just use your list...
have a look at this one

```
    public class sing
{
    public string singName {
        get { return _singName; }
        set { _singName = value; }
    }

    private string _singName;
    public DateTime singStart {
        get { return _singStart; }
        set { _singStart = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _singStart;
    public DateTime singEnd {
        get { return _singEnd; }
        set { _singEnd = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _singEnd;


    public void findSing(System.DateTime usersDate)
    {
        List<sing> ListOfSings = new List<sing>();

        sing scorpio = new sing();
        System.DateTime startD = new System.DateTime(1910, 10, 23);
        System.DateTime endD = new System.DateTime(1910, 11, 21);
        scorpio.singName = "scorpio";
        scorpio.singStart = startD;
        scorpio.singEnd = endD;
        ListOfSings.Add(scorpio);
        //' ....etc all the others

        dynamic hismonth = usersDate.Month;
        dynamic hisDay = usersDate.Day;

        System.DateTime fixedDate = new System.DateTime(1910, hismonth, hisDay);

        dynamic q = (from i in ListOfSings where i.singStart >= fixedDate && i.singEnd <= fixedDatei).ToList;

        MessageBox.Show("your sing is: " + q.FirstOrDefault.singName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The David Božjak's answer is a great choice.

I think the class could be abstract and implemented for every sign.
Also the StartDate, EndDate and the date pass as parameter need to ignore the year.
I made in this way:

```
public abstract class StarSign
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly DateTime StartDate;
    public readonly DateTime EndDate;

    protected StarSign(string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        Name = name;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public virtual bool Contains(DateTime date)
    {
        date = new DateTime(1, date.Month, date.Year);
        return date >= StartDate && date <= EndDate;
    }
}

public class AquariusStarSign : StarSign
{
    public AquariusStarSign()
        : base("Aquarius", new DateTime(1, 1, 21), new DateTime(1, 2, 18))
    {
    }
}

public class CapricornStarSign : StarSign
{
    public CapricornStarSign()
        : base("Capricorn", new DateTime(1, 12, 21), new DateTime(1, 1, 20))
    {
    }

    public override bool Contains(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.Month == StartDate.Month)
            return date.Day >= StartDate.Day;

        if (date.Month == EndDate.Month)
            return date.Day <= EndDate.Day;

        return false;
    }
}
```